# Getting MLE(Memory Limit Error) in my following code. Tried solving ROUND C 2019(Problem A- Wiggle Walk) Kickstart question

Tags: c++, stl

```
I AM GETTING MLE ERROR. Please suggest strategies to avoid this error. I am getting the correct answer though.
```

**QUESTION -**
Problem
Banny has just bought a new programmable robot. Eager to test his coding skills, he has placed the robot in a grid of squares with R rows (numbered 1 to R from north to south) and C columns (numbered 1 to C from west to east). The square in row r and column c is denoted (r, c).

Initially the robot starts in the square (SR, SC). Banny will give the robot N instructions. Each instruction is one of N, S, E or W, instructing the robot to move one square north, south, east or west respectively.

If the robot moves into a square that it has been in before, the robot will continue moving in the same direction until it reaches a square that it has not been in before. Banny will never give the robot an instruction that will cause it to move out of the grid.

Can you help Banny determine which square the robot will finish in, after following the N instructions?

Input
The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case starts with a line containing the five integers N, R, C, SR and SC, the number of instructions, the number of rows, the number of columns, the robot's starting row and starting column, respectively.

Then, another line follows containing a single string of N characters; the i-th of these characters is the i-th instruction Banny gives the robot (one of N, S, E or W, as described above).

Output
For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: r c, where x is the test case number (starting from 1), r is the row the robot finishes in and c is the column the robot finishes in.

Limits
Memory limit: 1GB.
1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
1 ≤ R ≤ 5 × 104.
1 ≤ C ≤ 5 × 104.
1 ≤ SR ≤ R.
1 ≤ SC ≤ C.
The instructions will not cause the robot to move out of the grid.

Test set 1 (Visible)
Time limit: 20 seconds.
1 ≤ N ≤ 100.

Test set 2 (Hidden)
Time limit: 60 seconds.
1 ≤ N ≤ 5 × 104.

Sample

Input

Output

3
5 3 6 2 3
EEWNS
4 3 3 1 1
SESE
11 5 8 3 4
NEESSWWNESE

Case #1: 3 2
Case #2: 3 3
Case #3: 3 7

```
**CODE -**
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
void trace_pos(vector<vector<int> >a,string s,int n,int r,int c,int t){
  for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
    if(s[i] == 'N'){
      while(a[r][c] == 1){
        r--;
      }
      a[r][c] = 1;
    }
    if(s[i] == 'S'){
      while(a[r][c] == 1){
        r++;
      }
      a[r][c] = 1;
    }
    if(s[i] == 'W'){
      while(a[r][c] == 1){
        c--;
      }
      a[r][c] = 1;
    }
    if(s[i] == 'E'){
      while(a[r][c] == 1){
        c++;
      }
      a[r][c] = 1;
    }
  }
  r = r + 1;
  c = c + 1;
  cout<<"Case #"<<t<<": "<<r<<" "<<c<<endl;
}
int main(){
  int t,q = 1;
  scanf("%d",&t);
  while(q <= t){
    int n,x,y,r,c;
    //char s[100];
    string s;
    cin>>n>>x>>y>>r>>c;
    r = r - 1;
    c = c - 1;
    cin>>s;
    //scanf("%s",s);
    //scanf("%d%d%d%d%d",n,x,y,r,c);
    vector<vector<int> >a(x,vector<int> (y,0));
    a[r][c] = 1;
    trace_pos(a,s,n,r,c,q);
    q++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting MLE because you are exceeding the memory limit. I am assuming that you have made a mistake writing the constraints. I think the limits for the big case is `1 <= N, R, C <= 5*10^4`. So in the worst case you are declaring a 2D vector of size `5*10^4 * 5*10^4` which is `25*10^8` which takes approximately 10 GB of memory. I think the problem doesn't allow you this much memory (No contest problem allows you that as much as I know).

Comment: Yeah you are right but for test set 1 the array 1 <= n <= 100 also the 2D matrices are 3*6, 3*3 and 5*8. Atleast for test case 1 the code must run right? Anyways the program is not well optimised as it will take a lot of memory.

Comment: You haven't mentioned that before. Can you share the link to the problem?

Comment: I have found the problem and checked your solution. If I create a vector of 100*100 size, then the verdict is Runtime Error which means the verdict is given for the whole problem, not just a part. So, you are getting MLE for the large case. 
I hope this answers your question. If you thinks so too, you can mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: Ohkay so it was for other test cases. Thanks a lot for letting me know :).